# Field default based on user location

Tags: default-value

I am looking at a way to assign default values on a few custom fields based on user location. We have a few users located in a different country and I would like to default a few fields based on this as is automatically done for currency in forecasts/opportunities.

Can this be done within Salesforce itself, or outside app needed?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  You should show what you've tried so far (or what you have researched so far)

Comment: You should be able to do this with Flow.  Check Salesforce Trailhead and other web resources for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - Screen Flow with $User formula**

How you might do this really depends on the data entry process.

For example, if it's worth creating a Screen Flow for creating these records, you should be able to create a formula in the Flow based on a field value on the $User (the user running the screen flow).

**Option 2 - custom Action**

I'm not as confident that this would work, but you could try the same approach as above but with a default value in a custom action based on the User.